# Python: Print text elements does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn scraping using python and new user of python just following a tutorial available online.  The print command does not work as shown in the video.  Below is the whole code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})
for item in g_data:
    print (item.text)

for item in g_data:
    print (item.contents[0].text)
    print (item.contents[1].text)

#Print text elements (**The command below does not work!!!!**)
for item in g_data:
    print (item.contents.find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"}).text)
```

Comment: `print (item.contents.find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"}).text)` - I think you need to iterate over `find_all` results: `for x in item.contents.find_all(...): print(x.text)`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When trying `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})`, BS doesn't find any `div` with `class="info"`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with BeautifulSoup, but shouldn't the `class` attribute be a list? `soup.find_all("div", {"class": ["info"]})`?

Comment: @AAP any news? did you manage to get what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing nested `html` with BeautifulSoup requires some practice, but once you've understood how it works it's all pretty neat.

There are many little flaws that prevent your code to work. I don't pretend to take all of them into account, but we can start by a step by step example which, hopefully, will give you a better understanding.

For instance, you can't do that:

```
item.contents.find_all("a")
```

Because `item.contents` is not a BeautifulSoup object. It is a basic Python `list` of what BeautifulSoup found in `item`. In order to continue searching in `item`, you have to query the object itself with `find_all`. So, you can do this instead:

```
for item in g_data:
    print(item.find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"}).text)
```

But it still isn't correct. Because of two things:

1. the result of `find_all` is is `list` of `objects`, which doesn't have a `text` method
2. anyway, BeautifulSoup objects don't have a `text` method. But they have a `contents` method

This `contents` method returns a list of strings found inside a tag. So, you have to do something like:

```
for item in g_data:
    links = item.find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})
    links_contents = [ link.contents[0] for link in links ]
    print("\n".join(links_contents))
```

Provided the rest is correct (which I'm not sure of), the above code would give you something like:

```
Content of my first link in the first item
Content of my second link in the first item
Content of my first link in the second item
Content of my second link in the second item
... and so forth
```

Comment: I have got this below

Comment: Hi Jivan, not working I have got error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 4, in <module>
    print("\n".join(links_contents))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Tag found

Comment: @AAP I tested this code again just now and it works perfectly

Comment: Hi Jivan, don't know but it is showing me same error. I am just copying and pasting your suggested code above. for item in g_data:
 links = item.find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})
 links_contents = [ link.contents[0] for link in links ]
 print("\n".join(links_contents))

Comment: what do you have if you do `print(len(g_data))`?

Comment: I have got a number => 32

Comment: any advice to fix my problem

Comment: @Jivan - Please can you explain how this last two lines of your for loop works? I is a tremendous work you have done. Also I dont understand the reason that in so many tutorials like <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk> `print item.contents[0].text` works but not when I do. How is it working for them?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})
for item in g_data:
    print (item.text)

for item in g_data:

print(item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
print(item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "StreetAddress"})[1].text)
```